# 2 webservers with different ports / apache2 and openslides with subdomain

Tags: apache2, subdomain, ports

An apache2 runs on my debian-server and listen to port 80. Additional I installed openslides. It has got a build-in webserver which listening to port 8080. Generally it is not a problem because it works when I try to get foobar.com:8080. I am looking for a solution, where the user write
lol.foobar.com and the what-ever routes it to foobar.com:8080. It would be more user-friendly and would be avoid some problems with firewalls.

My first idea was in sites-available like

ServerName lol.foobar.com

But I've got another think coming..

Any ideas?

Greetings

bengoshi